# Grouping elements of list by their membership order on another list

Tags: python, list, set

If I have a list `x` of consecutive integers (each consecutive integer occurs at least once)

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4]
```

representing the group memberships of another list, `y`

```
y = [0, 0, 100, 30, 2000, 100, 1000, 40, 4]
```

What's the cleanest way to extract a list of all the groupings, `z`? (Note: the order within each sublist in `z` does not matter.)

```
z == [[0,0], [100, 100, 1000], [2000], [30], [40, 4]]
```

I have a gut feeling that I can do it in 1 line but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham My bad, it's a typo.

Comment: @jDo That's correct, my 3rd line is supposed to return `True`.

Comment: @Katie how does `[[0,0], [100, 100, 1000], [2000], [30], [40, 4]]` come about exactly? Are we talking first digit grouping?

Comment: Ah okay. Forget the comment then.

Comment: @Katie, you can do it in one line, just not very efficiently

Comment: @PadraicCunningham For the element `y[i]`, put it in group `x[i]`.

Comment: @Katie, is this code golf or is there another reason you want to do it in a single line?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hm, I'm trying to optimize away for an ugly looking for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of lists (implemented using `defaultdict`), and then update each index location with the corresponding value.  This was done using zip to pair the results.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

for key, val in zip(x, y):
    dd[key].append(val)

>>> dd.values()
[[0, 0], [100, 100, 1000], [2000], [30], [40, 4]]
```

To guarantee the output matches the sorted order of keys:

```
>>> [dd[key] for key in sorted(dd.keys())]
[[0, 0], [100, 100, 1000], [2000], [30], [40, 4]]
```

**Timings**

```
x = x * 10000
y = y * 10000

%%timeit
od = OrderedDict()
for k,v in zip(x, y):
    od.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.7 ms per loop

%%timeit
dd = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in zip(x, y):
    dd[key].append(val)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: The order of `dd.values()` seems like it would be arbitrary ... Is that what OP wants?

Comment: Yes, arbitrary order is fine! Thanks!

Comment: Nice to add the timings

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the order, have readable and efficient code using a for loop with an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4]

y = [0, 0, 100, 30, 2000, 100, 1000, 40, 4]

from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()
for k,v in zip(x, y):
    od.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(od.values())
[[0, 0], [100, 100, 1000], [30], [2000], [40, 4]]
```

Bar the import and dict creation, it is two lines of code to create the pairings which I think is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I like the `defaultdict` solution. In order to get away from the unused list comprehension you could pair it with a `reduce`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
z = reduce(lambda dct, kv: dct[kv[0]].append(kv[1]) or dct, zip(x,y), \     
           defaultdict(list))
```

This works for both Python2 and Python3.
In Python2 you can use the argument unpacking (a shame it was removed in 3):

```
z = reduce(lambda dct, (key,value): dct[key].append(value) or dct, zip(x,y), \     
           defaultdict(list))
```

And it is your one-line solution - I split it but you wouldn't have to :-)